# HTML reuse, create template

Tags: html, asp.net, templates, user-controls, code-reuse

After about a year doing Asp.net web forms, I stepped out (for the most part) from the .net world.

I'm now working on a webapp that uses a lot of client side scripting and uses WebAPI for data access.

I have a HTML section that allows note taking. I would like to make this HTML section into a template that I can reuse elsewhere on the site (e.g., insert this piece of HTML code into another web page).

I'm a bit befuddled on how to go about this. Think of my problem as trying to create a "user control" in asp.net web forms ... only that I am not using web forms. Just good old fashioned HTML, CSS, Javascript, jquery, and knockout. Conceptually, I'd think that others have been in the same spot as myself.

Can anyone elaborate a solution or at least provide some pointers? Thanks !

Comment: You should probably remove the "asp.net" tag (and possibly "user-controls") if you are using good old fashioned HTML as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with http://mustache.github.io/, I think it is perfect for webapps

Answer (score 0):

I've personally use Backbone over knockout, so I might be a bit off, but Knockout has template creation as well. Id take a look at [this documentation on template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). Unfortunately I can't give you a clear answer, but looking deeper into knockout would be a good place to start. Since your using knockout already its probably best to not add another technology.

Answer (score 0):

There are many templating solutions that work well for html.  Here is [modest](https://github.com/goalzen/modest):

**main.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="modest-preview.js"></script>
    <include>mySection</include>
  </head>
  <body>
    <mySection/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**mySection.xml**

```
<section><p>Hello</p></section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a file and use an iframe.

For example, maybe you want it to be called 'editor.html'. You would create the file so it could function as a page on its own. Then on the page you need it, put:

```
<iframe src="editor.html">
```